# Properties of histogram equalization? Enhance contrast without artefacts?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, histogram, equalizer

In my case histogram equalization produces a lot of artifacts on shaded areas after Canny processing. Actually these areas contain very slow color variations, but they are enhanced by equalizer.

Is there a method to enhance contrast linearly, i.e. just make darkest pixel black and lightest pixel white, remaining all other pixels being of the same relative intensity?

**UPDATE**

How to make automatic gamma or contrast correction, so that histogram correction does?

Comment: You can have a look at http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider [gamma correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) for your pixels.